# Automatically changing text to hyperlinks in Google Docs

Tags: google-drive, links

Is it possible to set up auto-correct in Google Docs so that it will automatically change a word to a hyperlink to said word?

For example, I type:

> facebook

What I want is for the word to then automatically convert to:

> http://www.facebook.com/

Where the word has now become the link.

How do I set this up in Google Docs?

Answer (score 1):

It's partially possible.

While editing text document, select **Preferences** from the **Tools** drop-down menu. Add new entry to replace `facebook` with `http://www.facebook.com`.

After you type `facebook` and press space, the text will be replaced, but will not become hyperlink. But if you now type a space at the end of replaced text, it does change to hyperlink.